# gdaldem - raster to RGB raster with color-relief

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdaldem

I have 6-layer raster with float value.
I have six different QGIS style with color value.

Here is image value from QGIS:

[image]

Here is a QGIS style (for 6 layer):

```xml
<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
<qgis version="2.18.20" minimumScale="inf" maximumScale="inf" hasScaleBasedVisibilityFlag="0">
  <pipe>
    <rasterrenderer opacity="1" alphaBand="0" classificationMax="inf" classificationMinMaxOrigin="Unknown" band="6" classificationMin="-999" type="singlebandpseudocolor">
      <rasterTransparency/>
      <rastershader>
        <colorrampshader colorRampType="DISCRETE" clip="0">
          <item alpha="255" value="-999" label="-999" color="#a9a9a9"/>
          <item alpha="255" value="5" label="0-5" color="#0000ff"/>
          <item alpha="255" value="10" label="5-10" color="#00f400"/>
          <item alpha="255" value="20" label="10-20" color="#ffff00"/>
          <item alpha="255" value="30" label="20-30" color="#e0a000"/>
          <item alpha="255" value="inf" label=">30" color="#ff0000"/>
        </colorrampshader>
      </rastershader>
    </rasterrenderer>
    <brightnesscontrast brightness="-12" contrast="0"/>
    <huesaturation colorizeGreen="128" colorizeOn="0" colorizeRed="255" colorizeBlue="128" grayscaleMode="0" saturation="0" colorizeStrength="100"/>
    <rasterresampler maxOversampling="2"/>
  </pipe>
  <blendMode>0</blendMode>
</qgis>
```

I convert it to `color-relief` file

```
-999 169 169 169 255
0 0 0 255 255
5 0 244 0 255
10 255 255 0 255
20 224 160 0 255
30 255 0 0 255
```

I use `gdaldem`:

```bsh
gdaldem color-relief -b 6 input.tif color-relief.txt output.tif
```

After I run this is problem with interpolation:

Correct image in QGIS:
[image]
Incorrect image from gdaldem:
[image]

How to set legend with interval value and disable interpolation of pixels?

I use `-nearest_color_entry` flag. It works but compartment is wrong.

`gdaldem color-relief -nearest_color_entry -b 6 input.tif color-relief.txt output.tif`

```
-999: 169 169 169 255
0-5: 0 0 255 255
5-10: 0 244 0 255
10-20: 255 255 0 255
20-30: 224 160 0 255
30-9999: 255 0 0 255
```

[image]

Comment: Under 'Matching mode' perhaps try 'Use closest RGBA quadruplet'.

Comment: Thanks I was use ```-nearest_color_entry``` flag. It is works but compartment is wrong.